# Why doesn't Oracle reset processes when I restart the database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am getting Oracle maximum processes exceeded error. To increase the the maximum allowed processes I log in as sysdba:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

I try to see processes parameter:

```
sql> show parameter processes
ERROR:
ORA-01012: not logged on
```

I presume that sqlplus is not able to login due to processes being exceeded.

I try to shutdown the instance so that processes will be closed:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-24323: value not allowed
ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (%s) exceeded
```

I try to kill the Oracle service, that should kill the processes:

```
$ sudo service oracle-xe restart
[sudo] password for kshitiz: 
Shutting down Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.
Stopping Oracle Net Listener.

Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.
```

I login as sysdba again but it gives the same error.

How do I kill the processes so that the database is manageable again? And how should I diagnose why this error is occuring (which application is responsible for hogging the database)?

I am on `Oracle 10g express` and `Ubuntu 13.10`.

Comment: If you have too many connections you should close those connections rather than restarting Oracle.

Comment: Shouldn't restarting Oracle terminate the connections?

Comment: Yes, but you should fix the *cause* of the problem, not the symptom

Comment: What if I only want to fix the symptom? If you don't know the answer let somebody else provide it.

Comment: If you only want to fix the symptom and not the cause, just keep killing the Oracle service. You're doing fine at that.

Comment: @DavidAldridge `killing the Oracle service` doesn't fix the problem. Increasing `processes` parameter does.

Comment: @KshitizSharma Yes, I know, it's pretty much Oracle DBA 101. And I think that a_horse_with_no_name knows as well, and would have told you if you hadn't got all "What if I only want to fix the symptom?  If you don't know the answer let somebody else provide it."

Comment: @DavidAldridge There seems to a communication mismatch here. When I say fix the symptom I mean I want to fix the error on the DB side only without modifying the application making too many connections (not in my scope). Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to increase the max number of processes allowed. But the problem is that in this state there is no way to do that since DB wouldn't take any commands. Even the commands to increment the process parameter would give the maximum processes exceeded error.

Kill all processes belonging to `oracle` user:

```
$ sudo su
$ su oracle
$ kill -9 -1
```

Check that all process are killed:

```
$ ps -ef | grep oracle
```

If not kill them using `kill -9 PID`. Now connect to database as `sysdba`:

```
$ su oracle
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Shutdown the database (1. Shutdown immediate would probably not work and give same `ORA-01012` error. 2. Since the processes are killed isn't the database already shutdown? That's what I thought but it seems that it keeps a record of the last state or something which isn't clear out until you run the following command):

```
SQL> shutdown abort
```

Now bring it up again:

```
SQL> startup
```

Modify the processes parameter to prevent this problem from recurring:

```
SQL> select count(*) from v$process;
SQL> alter system set processes=300 scope=spfile;
```

Restart database:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
SQL> startup
```

Check that max processes have increased:

```
SQL> show parameter processes
```

**Edit:**
After all of this for some strange reason my application wasn't connecting to DB, though SQL plus was working just fine. So as a last step I restarted the oracle service:

```
$ sudo service oracle-xe restart
```

This got everything working for me.

Comment: @Benas You'll have to translate the commands to windows equivalents or Google it. Another user might be using Solaris or HP-UX. It's not possible for me to provide a guide for every platform.